# Creating more detailed Table Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create more detailed table cells. An example I found is the reddit.com client AlienBlue. Each cell has an image, the title of the post, then below it four other pieces of text. How can I "layer" text in a table cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you should subclass [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for custom User interface of a cell in a table view.
Also look at: [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for other options with regard to table view.

Probably your subclassed UiTableViewCell will have custom fields for title (UILabel), caption (UILabel) and for an image (UIImageView)

Examples:

1. [Crafting Custom UITableView Cells](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)
2. [Customize Table View Cells For UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to create a custom `UITableViewCell`. It's quite trivial, and can be done either entirely in code (my favorite) or through IB.

Google `custom UITableView cell` for some great tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **NSMutableArray** of **NSMUtableDictionary**, as opposed to NSArray or NSMutableArray, to hold data (strings, images, ...).
2. Set the table cell style property to **UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle** so that the table can display the detailedTextLabel (cell.detailTextLabel.text).
3. You can set an image to the table cell.

Example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...
UIImage *image = [[list1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:key1a];
cell.imageView.image = image;
NSString *categoryname = [[list1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:key1b];
cell.textLabel.text = categoryname;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[list1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:key1e];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[appdelegate.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        UIImage *image = [[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        return cell;
     }
```